# Where to place tsconfig.json in Symfony Encore to define TypeScript config?

Tags: javascript, symfony, typescript, ts-loader, webpack-encore

Symfony Encore now supports using TypeScript by default ([Add support to enableTypescriptLoader](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/pull/50)), and it works great. However, I would like to configure my TypeScript configuration using a tsconfig.json file.

I tried figuring out where to place this, but I got lost in the rabbithole and didn't figure out where I should place the file for ts-loader to pick it up. Or if there is a configuration that enables this.

Comment: Looks like [that comment](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/pull/50/files#diff-168726dbe96b3ce427e7fedce31bb0bcR349) is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Having the `tsconfig.json` in same place of `webpack.config.js` should do the job.

`ts-loader` assumes the same as default configuration.

Check ts-loader configuration documentation, there is one option for configuring file name in case it is located somewhere else.

UPDATE:
Keep an eye on [this docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend) there is some [documentation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/8136) on the way.

Configuration goes like:

```
.enableTypeScriptLoader(function (typeScriptConfigOptions) {
    typeScriptConfigOptions.transpileOnly = true;
    typeScriptConfigOptions.configFileName = '/path/to/tsconfig.json';
});
```

But again, loader defaults for `configFileName` option is: `tsconfig.json` so, should be enough having the file in same directory of `webpack.config.js` or in same directory from where you run webpack, not sure now actually. I always run webpack from same dir as `webpack.config.js` :)

Cheers

Comment: It is working, I was just messing around too much when working. This is the correct answer.

Comment: How do you do this for assetic instead of webpack?

Comment: @zakdances I think you should post this as a new question, though, this issue: https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/5 may help you understand the scope/differences of both libraries.

Comment: This solved my problems with configuring `webpack encore` on `symfony-4`, standard configurations recommended on webpack/ts-loader pages are not working...